# [gitlab ci]: How to wait for a job, only if this job has started, but not if it is skipped

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

**Question:** Is there a way to tell gitlab to only wait on an earlier pipeline step, if this step has not been skipped?

**Context:** We did some optimization steps for our continuous integration pipeline.
With the help of the `cache` keyword provided by gitlab, we only install our nodejs dependencies once per branch in a separate build step. The `node_modules` folder is then persisted in the cache and made available to all subsequent steps and pipeline runs for this specific branch. The pipeline only re-installs the dependencies and updates the cache, if the `package-lock.json` has changed in a new commit.
See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache

The caching does work well so far, the only issue is that I cannot configure subsequent jobs to wait for the `install` job. If I would do so - for example with `needs: ["install"]` -, the pipeline would get blocked on all runs, if the `package-lock.json` has not changed and thus, the `install` step has been skipped.

**Example:**

```
install:
  stage: "install"
  rules:
    - changes:
        - package-lock.json
  needs: [ ]
  cache: 
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PROJECT_DIR
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm ci ...

build:
  stage: "build"
  needs: [ ]
  cache: 
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PROJECT_DIR
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    policy: pull
  script:
    - ./build.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/
```

Comment: It seems that just removing the needs array, does help in this case, if the `build` step is in a subsequent stage in relation to the `install` step